# Can I convert my metamask wallet into a multisign wallet?

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, smart-contract-wallets

Wondering if it's possible to convert a wallet into an multisig wallet which would require multiple signatures to carry out transaction on the wallet.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean wallet is the private-public key pair and ETH address created by Metamask. Because your Metamask wallet is associated with a single private key so it's not possible to "convert" it into a multi-sig wallet. However, it can be used to access a multi-sig wallet created elsewhere. You can create another multi-sig wallet with either method below:

1. Without smart contract: Use [ECDSA threshold signature or multi-party signature](https://github.com/ZenGo-X/multi-party-ecdsa) (which is quite complex to most normal users).
2. With Smart Contract: you can copy from some open source solidity repo like this [one](https://github.com/gnosis/MultiSigWallet). In this method, there is a significant risk of deploying and using smart contract wrongly leading to loss of fund.

The recommended and simplest way is to use `Gnosis Safe` which has [step-by-step guide from their website](https://help.gnosis-safe.io/en/articles/3876461-creating-a-safe-on-a-web-browser)